# Monitoring Tool for Microservices

Tags: linux, monitoring, network-monitor, system-monitor

There are some Micorservices running on RHEL7. I want to monitor those services(each service is running on specific port). There should be an email notification whenever the services goes down. Is there any tool from which i can monitor those ports or services and will receive email whenever it goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use monit for this.

Please follow the below link to configure monit:

https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-and-setup-monit-linux-process-and-services-monitoring-program/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiRt3mY7Rrw&list=PLtK75qxsQaMLZSo7KL-PmiRarU7hrpnwK&index=39       and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThcaW4MVGLY&list=PLtK75qxsQaMLZSo7KL-PmiRarU7hrpnwK&index=40

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As you see, all well-received answers here are [more than just a link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232). Please consider [edit]ing your answer and add more information about the software, especially how it meets the requirements in the question.